# Steam controller (outside of Steam)

Tags: steam, gamepad, emulation

I'm looking into getting a steam controller for my computer because I love playing classic games on emulators, and I dislike having to sync and resync my PS3 controller to the console and computer whenever I switch back and forth.

Will a steam controller work or be recognized as a generic controller input device so I can map it to my various emulators? Or does it strictly work with steam?

Answer (score 0):

The steam controller works as a generic mouse until you start Steam and open big picture. I have had trouble with the mouse function over wireless when Steam isn't launched, but most of that really doesn't matter. Steam allows you to set shortcuts from inside the program. If your emulators have desktop launchers, or you are willing to create a desktop launcher for them, then you can also open them as non-steam games, which will allow you to set custom controller bindings on a per-game basis from the steam overlay.

So the answer is yes and no.

My recommendation is that you try setting your games as steam shortcuts, and then try and set controller bindings to either gamepad outputs, or keyboard and mouse outputs.

The steam controller, in my opinion, is great because of this- while you need the steam overlay, it really can emulate a keyboard and mouse, and do so much more than a traditional gamepad.